# linking to image on https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/ ? is this secure and permanent?

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api

I was wondering what was the best approach to save (cache) image related post.
I managed to show post with photo in my app bur I wonder if I should save the link to the photo, which is in a form :
https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCtnu73h9S_VKCU&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-ash3%2Fs480x480%2F946293_10151384977470588_1749379689_n.jpg

or if I should copy and serve from my own CDN ?

Thanks !